# jQuery Mobile shows all pages when using a multi-page template

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm creating a simple jQuery Mobile 1.3.0 single-file, multi-page document. When it loads, all of the page divs display on the page. What is wrong with the code?

This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Daily Exercise</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.jpg"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .content    {margin-top:-20px;}
        .main       {font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; color:#444; font-family:"Trebuchet MS"; margin-left:0px;}
        .small      {font-weight:normal; font-size:11px; color:#666; font-family:"Courier New";}

        .day        {display:inline-block; width:85px;}
        .exercise   {display:inline-block; width:145px;}
        .reps       {display:inline-block; width:110px; text-align:right;}
        .part       {display:inline-block; width:40px; text-align:right;}

        .test       {border:1px red solid;}
    </style>
</head>
<body> 

<!-- START PAGE -->
<div id="main" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Daily Exercise</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" class="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false">
            <li><a href="#hiit-legs" data-transition="slide"><span class="main day">Monday</span><span class="small">(HIIT & Legs)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#chest-triceps" data-transition="slide"><span class="main day">Tuesday</span><span class="small">(Chest & Triceps)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#back-biceps" data-transition="slide"><span class="main day">Wednesday</span><span class="small">(Back & Biceps)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#hiit-legs-2" data-transition="slide"><span class="main day">Thursday</span><span class="small">(HIIT & Legs)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#chest-back-core" data-transition="slide"><span class="main day">Friday</span><span class="small">(Chest, Back & Core)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#shoulders-biceps" data-transition="slide"><span class="main day">Saturday</span><span class="small">(Shoulders & Biceps)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#chest-back-core" data-transition="slide"><span class="main day">Sunday</span><span class="small">(Chest, Back & Core)</span></a></li>
        </ul>   
    </div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="content" class="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false">
            <li><a href="#rules-goals" data-transition="slide"><span class="main day">Rules & Goals</span></a></li>
        </ul>   
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->


<!-- HIIT & LEGS -->
<div id="hiit-legs" date-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>HIIT & Legs</h1>
        <a href="#main" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">Back</a>      
    </div><!-- /header -->  
    <div data-role="content" class="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="d">
            <li data-role="list-divider">HIIT</li>
            <li><a href="#hiit-treadmill" data-transition="slide"><span class="main exercise">Treadmill</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#hiit-outside" data-transition="slide"><span class="main exercise">Outside</span></a></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">Legs</li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Split Squats</span><span class="small reps">(25x - 5 lbs)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Switch Squats</span><span class="small reps">(25x - Body)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Deadlift Squats</span><span class="small reps">(25x - Body)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Wall Squats</span><span class="small reps">(60s - 5 lbs)</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->


<!-- CHEST & TRICEPS -->
<div id="chest-triceps" date-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Chest & Triceps</h1>
        <a href="#main" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">Back</a>      
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" class="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="d">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Set 1</li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Decline Push-Ups</span><span class="small reps">(20x, Body)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Table Dips</span><span class="small reps">(20x, Body)</span></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">Set 2</li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Military Push-Ups</span><span class="small reps">(20x, Body)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Tricep Extend</span><span class="small reps">(15x, Burg)</span></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">Set 3</li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Alt Push-Ups</span><span class="small reps">(20x, Body)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Stool Dips</span><span class="small reps">(15x, Body)</span></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">Set 4</li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Wide Push-Ups</span><span class="small reps">(20x, Body)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Kick Backs</span><span class="small reps">(15x, Burg)</span></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">Set 5</li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Push-Ups</span><span class="small reps">(Max, Body)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">X-Body Blows</span><span class="small reps">(25x, Burg)</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->


<!-- BACK & BICEPS -->
<div id="back-biceps" date-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Back & Biceps</h1>
        <a href="#main" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">Back</a>      
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" class="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="d">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Set 1</li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Narrow Pull-Ups</span><span class="small reps">(10x, Body)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Normal Curls</span><span class="small reps">(15x, 25 lbs)</span></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">Set 2</li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Heavy Pants</span><span class="small reps">(15x, 3-Band)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Static Curls</span><span class="small reps">(8x, 25 lbs)</span></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">Set 3</li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Wide Pull-Ups</span><span class="small reps">(10x, Body)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Out Curls</span><span class="small reps">(15x, 25 lbs)</span></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">Set 4</li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Lawnmowers</span><span class="small reps">(15x, 3-Band)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">7-7-7 Curls</span><span class="small reps">(15x, 25 lbs)</span></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">Set 5</li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Chin-Ups</span><span class="small reps">(Max, Body)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Hammer Curls</span><span class="small reps">(15x, 25 lbs)</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->


<!-- HIIT & LEGS 2 -->
<div id="hiit-legs2" date-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>HIIT & Legs</h1>
        <a href="#main" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">Back</a>      
    </div><!-- /header -->  
    <div data-role="content" class="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="d">
            <li data-role="list-divider">HIIT</li>
            <li><a href="#hiit-treadmill" data-transition="slide"><span class="main exercise">Treadmill</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#hiit-outside" data-transition="slide"><span class="main exercise">Outside</span></a></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">Legs</li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">80/20 Speed Squats</span><span class="small reps">(25x - Body)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Step-Back Lunges</span><span class="small reps">(25x - 5 lbs)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Deadlift Squats</span><span class="small reps">(25x - Body)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Wall Squats</span><span class="small reps">(60s - 5 lbs)</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->


<!-- CHEST, BACK & CORE -->
<div id="chest-back-core" date-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Chest, Back & Core</h1>
        <a href="#main" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">Back</a>      
    </div><!-- /header -->  
    <div data-role="content" class="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="d">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Chest</li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">100 Push-Ups</span><span class="small reps">(20 x 5)</span></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">Back</li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">50 Pull-Ups</span><span class="small reps">(10 x 5)</span></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">Core</li>
            <li><a href="#ab-ripper" data-transition="slide"><span class="main exercise">Ab Ripper</span><span class="small reps">(270)</span></a></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Superman</span><span class="small reps">(10s x 5)</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->


<!-- HIIT-TREADMILL -->
<div id="hiit-treadmill" date-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>HIIT Treadmill</h1>
        <a href="#main" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">Back</a>      
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" class="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false" data-divider-theme="d">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Warmup</li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Fast Walk</span><span class="small">3 mph - 8%</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Fast Walk</span><span class="small">3 mph - 12%</span></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">Intervals (x6)</li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Sprint</span><span class="small">8 mph - 12%</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Fast Walk</span><span class="small">3 mph - 12%</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Fast Walk</span><span class="small">3 mph - 12%</span></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">Cooldown</li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Fast Walk</span><span class="small">3 mph - 12%</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Fast Walk</span><span class="small">3 mph - 8%</span></li>
        </ul>   
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<!-- HIIT-OUTSIDE -->
<div id="hiit-outside" date-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>HIIT - Outside</h1>
        <a href="#main" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">Back</a>      
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" class="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false" data-divider-theme="d">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Warmup</li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Light Jog</span><span class="small">5 min</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Light Run</span><span class="small">2 min</span></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">Intervals (x6)</li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Sprint</span><span class="small">30 sec</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Walk</span><span class="small">60 sec</span></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">Cooldown</li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Walk Home</span><span class="small">? min</span></li>
        </ul>   
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<!-- RULES & GOALS -->
<div id="rules-goals" date-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>HIIT - Outside</h1>
        <a href="#main" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">Back</a>      
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" class="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false" data-divider-theme="d">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Rules</li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">5 x Fast 16/8</span><span class="small reps">9pm to 1pm, 1,750</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">2 x Fast 20/4</span><span class="small reps">9pm to 5pm, 500</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Train Fasted</span><span class="small reps">12pm or 4pm</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">During: BCAAs</span><span class="small reps">10g</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">After: Creatine</span><span class="small reps">5g</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">After: High Protein</span><span class="small reps">1g/Lean Weight</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Largest Meal</span><span class="small reps">1g/Lean Weight</span></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">Goals</li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">8% Body Fat</span><span class="small"></span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">140 lbs Lean</span><span class="small">152 lbs total</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">150 lbs Lean</span><span class="small">163 lbs total</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Food Discipline</span><span class="small"></span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Weight Maintained</span><span class="small"></span></li>
        </ul>   
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<!-- AB RIPPER -->
<div id="ab-ripper" date-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Ab Ripper</h1>
        <a href="#main" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">Back</a>      
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" class="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false" data-divider-theme="d">
            <li><span class="main exercise">Crunches</span><span class="small">(x20)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Leg Lifts</span><span class="small">(x20)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Bicycles</span><span class="small">(x20)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">In & Out (V)</span><span class="small">(x20)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">L/R Crunches</span><span class="small">(2x20)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Hip Rock & Raise</span><span class="small">(x20)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">V-Up Roll-Up</span><span class="small">(x20)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">L/R Oblique V-Up</span><span class="small">(2x20)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Crunchy Frog</span><span class="small">(x20)</span></li>
            <li><span class="main exercise">Mason Twist</span><span class="small">(x50)</span></li>
        </ul>   
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On my local machine this code works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `date-role` instead of `data-role` which is the correct attribute. Therefore try to change all the `date-role="page"` to `data-role="page"` and the problem will be solved.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Daily Exercise</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.jpg" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .content {
                margin-top:-20px;
            }
            .main {
                font-weight:bold;
                font-size:14px;
                color:#444;
                font-family:"Trebuchet MS";
                margin-left:0px;
            }
            .small {
                font-weight:normal;
                font-size:11px;
                color:#666;
                font-family:"Courier New";
            }
            .day {
                display:inline-block;
                width:85px;
            }
            .exercise {
                display:inline-block;
                width:145px;
            }
            .reps {
                display:inline-block;
                width:110px;
                text-align:right;
            }
            .part {
                display:inline-block;
                width:40px;
                text-align:right;
            }
            .test {
                border:1px red solid;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- START PAGE -->
        <div id="main" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                 <h1>Daily Exercise</h1>

            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content" class="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#hiit-legs" data-transition="slide"><span class="main day">Monday</span><span class="small">(HIIT & Legs)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#chest-triceps" data-transition="slide"><span class="main day">Tuesday</span><span class="small">(Chest & Triceps)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#back-biceps" data-transition="slide"><span class="main day">Wednesday</span><span class="small">(Back & Biceps)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#hiit-legs-2" data-transition="slide"><span class="main day">Thursday</span><span class="small">(HIIT & Legs)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#chest-back-core" data-transition="slide"><span class="main day">Friday</span><span class="small">(Chest, Back & Core)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#shoulders-biceps" data-transition="slide"><span class="main day">Saturday</span><span class="small">(Shoulders & Biceps)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#chest-back-core" data-transition="slide"><span class="main day">Sunday</span><span class="small">(Chest, Back & Core)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
            <div data-role="content" class="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#rules-goals" data-transition="slide"><span class="main day">Rules & Goals</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->
        <!-- HIIT & LEGS -->
        <div id="hiit-legs" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                 <h1>HIIT & Legs</h1>

                <a href="#main" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">Back</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content" class="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="d">
                    <li data-role="list-divider">HIIT</li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#hiit-treadmill" data-transition="slide"><span class="main exercise">Treadmill</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#hiit-outside" data-transition="slide"><span class="main exercise">Outside</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Legs</li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Split Squats</span><span class="small reps">(25x - 5 lbs)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Switch Squats</span><span class="small reps">(25x - Body)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Deadlift Squats</span><span class="small reps">(25x - Body)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Wall Squats</span><span class="small reps">(60s - 5 lbs)</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->
        <!-- CHEST & TRICEPS -->
        <div id="chest-triceps" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                 <h1>Chest & Triceps</h1>

                <a href="#main" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">Back</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content" class="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="d">
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Set 1</li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Decline Push-Ups</span><span class="small reps">(20x, Body)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Table Dips</span><span class="small reps">(20x, Body)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Set 2</li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Military Push-Ups</span><span class="small reps">(20x, Body)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Tricep Extend</span><span class="small reps">(15x, Burg)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Set 3</li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Alt Push-Ups</span><span class="small reps">(20x, Body)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Stool Dips</span><span class="small reps">(15x, Body)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Set 4</li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Wide Push-Ups</span><span class="small reps">(20x, Body)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Kick Backs</span><span class="small reps">(15x, Burg)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Set 5</li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Push-Ups</span><span class="small reps">(Max, Body)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">X-Body Blows</span><span class="small reps">(25x, Burg)</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->
        <!-- BACK & BICEPS -->
        <div id="back-biceps" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                 <h1>Back & Biceps</h1>

                <a href="#main" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">Back</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content" class="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="d">
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Set 1</li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Narrow Pull-Ups</span><span class="small reps">(10x, Body)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Normal Curls</span><span class="small reps">(15x, 25 lbs)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Set 2</li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Heavy Pants</span><span class="small reps">(15x, 3-Band)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Static Curls</span><span class="small reps">(8x, 25 lbs)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Set 3</li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Wide Pull-Ups</span><span class="small reps">(10x, Body)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Out Curls</span><span class="small reps">(15x, 25 lbs)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Set 4</li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Lawnmowers</span><span class="small reps">(15x, 3-Band)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">7-7-7 Curls</span><span class="small reps">(15x, 25 lbs)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Set 5</li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Chin-Ups</span><span class="small reps">(Max, Body)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Hammer Curls</span><span class="small reps">(15x, 25 lbs)</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->
        <!-- HIIT & LEGS 2 -->
        <div id="hiit-legs2" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                 <h1>HIIT & Legs</h1>

                <a href="#main" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">Back</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content" class="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="d">
                    <li data-role="list-divider">HIIT</li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#hiit-treadmill" data-transition="slide"><span class="main exercise">Treadmill</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#hiit-outside" data-transition="slide"><span class="main exercise">Outside</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Legs</li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">80/20 Speed Squats</span><span class="small reps">(25x - Body)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Step-Back Lunges</span><span class="small reps">(25x - 5 lbs)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Deadlift Squats</span><span class="small reps">(25x - Body)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Wall Squats</span><span class="small reps">(60s - 5 lbs)</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->
        <!-- CHEST, BACK & CORE -->
        <div id="chest-back-core" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                 <h1>Chest, Back & Core</h1>

                <a href="#main" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">Back</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content" class="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="d">
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Chest</li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">100 Push-Ups</span><span class="small reps">(20 x 5)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Back</li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">50 Pull-Ups</span><span class="small reps">(10 x 5)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Core</li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#ab-ripper" data-transition="slide"><span class="main exercise">Ab Ripper</span><span class="small reps">(270)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Superman</span><span class="small reps">(10s x 5)</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->
        <!-- HIIT-TREADMILL -->
        <div id="hiit-treadmill" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                 <h1>HIIT Treadmill</h1>

                <a href="#main" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">Back</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content" class="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false" data-divider-theme="d">
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Warmup</li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Fast Walk</span><span class="small">3 mph - 8%</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Fast Walk</span><span class="small">3 mph - 12%</span>
                    </li>
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Intervals (x6)</li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Sprint</span><span class="small">8 mph - 12%</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Fast Walk</span><span class="small">3 mph - 12%</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Fast Walk</span><span class="small">3 mph - 12%</span>
                    </li>
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Cooldown</li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Fast Walk</span><span class="small">3 mph - 12%</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Fast Walk</span><span class="small">3 mph - 8%</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->
        <!-- HIIT-OUTSIDE -->
        <div id="hiit-outside" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                 <h1>HIIT - Outside</h1>

                <a href="#main" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">Back</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content" class="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false" data-divider-theme="d">
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Warmup</li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Light Jog</span><span class="small">5 min</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Light Run</span><span class="small">2 min</span>
                    </li>
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Intervals (x6)</li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Sprint</span><span class="small">30 sec</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Walk</span><span class="small">60 sec</span>
                    </li>
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Cooldown</li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Walk Home</span><span class="small">? min</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->
        <!-- RULES & GOALS -->
        <div id="rules-goals" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                 <h1>HIIT - Outside</h1>

                <a href="#main" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">Back</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content" class="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false" data-divider-theme="d">
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Rules</li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">5 x Fast 16/8</span><span class="small reps">9pm to 1pm, 1,750</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">2 x Fast 20/4</span><span class="small reps">9pm to 5pm, 500</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Train Fasted</span><span class="small reps">12pm or 4pm</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">During: BCAAs</span><span class="small reps">10g</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">After: Creatine</span><span class="small reps">5g</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">After: High Protein</span><span class="small reps">1g/Lean Weight</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Largest Meal</span><span class="small reps">1g/Lean Weight</span>
                    </li>
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Goals</li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">8% Body Fat</span><span class="small"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">140 lbs Lean</span><span class="small">152 lbs total</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">150 lbs Lean</span><span class="small">163 lbs total</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Food Discipline</span><span class="small"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Weight Maintained</span><span class="small"></span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->
        <!-- AB RIPPER -->
        <div id="ab-ripper" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                 <h1>Ab Ripper</h1>

                <a href="#main" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">Back</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content" class="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false" data-divider-theme="d">
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Crunches</span><span class="small">(x20)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Leg Lifts</span><span class="small">(x20)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Bicycles</span><span class="small">(x20)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">In & Out (V)</span><span class="small">(x20)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">L/R Crunches</span><span class="small">(2x20)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Hip Rock & Raise</span><span class="small">(x20)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">V-Up Roll-Up</span><span class="small">(x20)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">L/R Oblique V-Up</span><span class="small">(2x20)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Crunchy Frog</span><span class="small">(x20)</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="main exercise">Mason Twist</span><span class="small">(x50)</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->
    </body>

</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Damn, it's so often the stupid little mistakes. Thanks Tolis.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
date-role
```

to

```
data-role
   ^
```

on all page `div`s exept `main`

Comment: Straight forward answer +1

Comment: What's the difference between this answer and my answer posted before? no problem :)

Comment: @TolisEmmanouilidis Why should they differ if we both saw the problem? And BTW I didn't see your answer until I posted mine after switching from html validator. But sorry anyway.